# Retain dropdown selected value after button submit

Tags: php

I need to retain the selected dropdown value after button submit, and I have used the following code for that:

```
<select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
  <option>Select One</option>
  <option selected="SELECTED">
    <?php if (!(strcmp("Processing", $_POST["status"]))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>
    Processing</option>
  <option>New</option>
  <option>pending</option>
  <option>Locked</option>
  <option>Ignore</option>
</select>
```

But when I select `Processing` and hit submit, it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens when you submit the form -- does it **set** the `status` `$_POST`? Have you tried debugging this? Also, why are you using `if (!(strcmp("Processing", $_POST["status"])))`? Can't you just use `if ($_POST["status"] !== "Processing")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** just use `if(isset($_POST["status"]) && $_POST["status"]=="Processing"){}`

**2nd :** you need to `set` `value attribute` for each `option`

```
<option value="Processing" <?php if(isset($_POST["status"]) && $_POST["status"]=="Processing") { echo " selected"; } ?>>Processing</option>
<option value="New" <?php if(isset($_POST["status"]) && $_POST["status"]=="New") { echo " selected"; } ?>>New</option>
......
```